# An internal error occurred during: "Refreshing Process Information". java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, eclipse-luna

Whenever I create a `folder under WebContent in Eclipse Luna`, this pops up even though the folder gets created.

[image]

The message is:

> ### Problem Occured
>
> 'Refreshing Process Information' has encountered a problem.
>
> An internal error occurred during: "Refreshing Process Information".
>
> ```
> An internal error occurred during: "Refreshing Process Information".
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
> ```

Why the ***java.lang.NullPointerException***?

***EDIT:***

***Attached Error Log:***

[image]
***These are the problems listed:***

> (X) An internal error occurred during: "Refreshing Process Information".
>   (!) Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
>   (!) Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
>   (X) Could not bind a reference of component Active Customer. The reference is: Reference[name = AnalyzationAndRenderService, interface = j...
>   (X) Could not bind a reference of component Active Customer. The reference is: Reference[name = AnalyzationAndRenderService, interface = j...
>   (!) [SCR] ComponentReference.bind(): bind method 'setAnalyzationAndRenderService' not found or it is not accessible!
>   (!) [SCR] Could not get the service object relevant to the reference. One possible reason is a circulation problem. Another possible reason is that Bu...
>   (X) FrameworkEvent ERROR
>   (X) Exception occurred while creating new instance of component Component[
>   (X) Exception occurred while creating new instance of component Component[

Comment: Under Window -> Show View -> Error Log you can find more information. Please post that as well here.

Comment: Your pictures are too small to read. Also, you can get some detailed info if you double click on one of the lines in the error log.

Comment: @David ten Hove: Exception stack trace shows NPE due to the JBOSS Plugin installed in Luna Eclipse. I think i should not bother about this then..It's has something to do with the internal functioning mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the .metadata folder and import the project again (just to be safe, make a copy of your project folder somewhere else.)

And are you using GIT in your project ?

Answer (score 0):

Even though it was the old post, this answer will helpful for someone.

Try to close and open the project, refreshed project get fixed the `NullPointerException` in my case.

Even though error is not getting fixed, close the project -> close eclipse -> open eclipse -> open project may fix your `NullPointerException`.